# Popover in a loop - JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, loops, popover

I'm a bit lost... I'm trying to use Popover but, the thing is I have many buttons in a table. Each buttons match with a user stored in my database.

My popover has the class "information" and id equal to the user id of my database.

Something like this:

```
<?php
    // Start Loop
    echo '<td><a href="#" class="information btn" id="'.$row->IdUser.'">Show Info</a></td>';
    ...
    // End loop
?>
```

And I don't know how to do to use popover in this case.

Thank you a lot for your help,
Lapinou.

Comment: A javascript and HTML code sample would be great: http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: Ok, here the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/r8ynw/8/ thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean bootstrap popover, you can add data-content attribute which would hold popover content for each button, e.g if you are also fetching it from database it would be something like this

```
<?php
// Start Loop
echo '<td><a href="#" class="information btn" data-content="'.$row->PopoverInfo.'" id="'.$row->IdUser.'">Show Info</a></td>';
...
// End loop
?>
```

then initialize it with javascript on dom ready

```
$(function(){
    $(".information").popover();
})
```

see more about bootstrap popover options [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

Comment: So simple XD Thank you a lot paulitto!